# How to implement reuse of a discount code used for a canceled order?

Tags: django

I have a Django project to implement discount codes.
The models are as follows:

```
class CouponCode(models.Model):
    max_usage = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    max_usage_per_user = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)
    code = CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    discount_percent = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0, validators=MaxValueValidator(100)])
    max_discount_amount = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    minimum_price = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(default=0)


class UsedCode(models.Model):
    customer = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(verbose_name='customer id')
    coupon = models.ForeignKey(CouponCode, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    order_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()


    @classmethod
    def has_reached_max_usage_for_user(cls, coupon, user):
        usages = cls.objects.filter(coupon=coupon, customer=user).count()
        if usages < coupon.max_usage_per_user:
            return False
        return True

    @classmethod
    def has_reached_max_usage(cls, coupon):
        usages = cls.objects.filter(coupon=coupon).count()
        if usages < coupon.max_usage:
            return False
        return True
```

Every time an order is created with a coupon code, a `UsedCode` object is created.
I want to implement a feature where the coupon code can be reused if the order is cancelled.
I prefer not to delete the objects so I can track the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to delete the object
You can add extra filed like :

```
class UsedCode(models.Model):
    customer = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(verbose_name='customer id')
    coupon = models.ForeignKey(CouponCode, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    order_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    reusable = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

And if the order cancelled set reusable to True

Then count the none cancelled orders

```
usages = cls.objects.filter(coupon=coupon, customer=user , reusable=False).count()
```